# Show questions (with answers) that a user has answered

Tags: discussion, data-explorer

Is there any way to display questions (and all the answers) that a particular user has answered.  That is, select all the questions that a particular person has answered and display 10 (or whatever number) of questions and all the answers per page.  Since I'm hoping for the world here, being able to specify a user and a tag would be even better.

Answer (score 6):

Does searching for user:nnnn [tag] do what you want? e.g.

`user:6177 [vms]`

[cliky linky](https://serverfault.com/search?q=user:6177%20%5Bvms%5D)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to run a query on the StackExchange Data Explorer:

http://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/new

I'm not very familiar with the database scheme, but this could be a start:

```
select top 10 q.Id, q.Title, q.CreationDate, a.Id, ...
from Posts a, Posts q
where a.OwnerUserId = <USERID>
and q.Id = a.ParentId
order by q.CreationDate desc
```